# Unable to fetch using RoleManagement API endpoints in azure graph-api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the azure Graph API to fetch the users having a particular role. Code snippet below as how I generated the authToken

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authString, false);
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _clientSecret);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
            if (_authenticationResult == null || true == CanAcquireToken)
            {
                authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_resAzureGraphAPI, clientCred).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                _authenticationResult = authenticationResult;
            }
            return _authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

Snapshot of the list of permissions the Graph API has on my application:
[GraphAPI permissions on application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61pTf.png)

I did my reading from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http to understand the API endpoint and the required set of permissions for the Graph API on the corresponding appRegistration.

I have provided the graph API with required permission set on the application which is under review.
However, the API request to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/{{beta}}/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=roleDefinitionId eq '{{roleDefnId-Guid}}'
```

always keeps failing with the error details

> Access token validation failure. Invalid audience

Note: The generated auth token is successfully fetching me info from "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http" mentioned calls

Comment: How did you generate the token? Could you update the steps in your question?

Comment: Hey Joy, have edited my post with authToken generation code snippet and the list of permissions I have provisioned to the GraphAPI on the application

Comment: BTW, the `https://graph.microsoft.com/{{beta}}/` should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/`, did you use the correct one?

Comment: The entire URL I was referring to was "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=roleDefinitionId eq 'Guid'" for this I have a doubt how would it check for the right application I'm referring to

Comment: Check my answer, any update?

Comment: Yes! I was referring to the wrong URL. I'm generating the authToken with the right endpoint now. Thank you!!

Comment: If your issue has been solved, could you accept it as answer? See how to accept: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

The permission of your app is correct, `Directory.ReadWrite.All` application permission is enough. I also test your code, it works fine.

Make sure the `_resAzureGraphAPI` in your code is `https://graph.microsoft.com` (just confirm it again, I know if it is wrong, you will not be able to call the api in your `Note`). I can just reproduce your issue with a wrong one, e.g. `https://graph.windows.net`.

If the `_resAzureGraphAPI` is correct, decode your token in https://jwt.io/, see it is the same as below.

[image]